# How to add Accessibility support for blind people in Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, accessibility

How to add Accessibility support for blind people in Wordpress site?
I searched a lot but could not find any plugin or something really valuable except some general blog posts.
I have created many website

> I heard about something called "braille" that is used for that purpose but does anyone have any clue about it? how can it be implemented in to wordpress?

Comment: "[Braille](http://code.google.com/p/braille/) has not been updated since July 2007, so there is no guarantee that it will work with current releases of WordPress, use it at your own risk"

Comment: Is there anything other than normal content that needs to be made accessible, such as videos or the like?

Comment: Quick not-perfect summary: If you provide alt text, caption any video, transcribe any audio, and have keyboard access to your content and links you're 80% there. Then forms labeling is the biggest remaining issue. You don't need to test with a screen reader (it can be counterproductive if you don't know how it functions) but a visual inspection tool such as [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)  for Firefox & Chrome or Web Accessibility Toolbar for IE can help you quickly and easily check for proper table coding and alt text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most vision impaired people use screen readers. The best ways to make your pages more accessible to them involve things like including skip links, clean semantic markup, alt tags, keyboard shortcuts and the like. There is a page [here](http://wpmu.org/25-ways-to-make-your-wordpress-website-more-accessible/) that lists some things you can do in general and how Wordpress stacks up specifically. I find the best thing to do is to try using my site with a screen reader and seeing how hard it is. If it is annoying, put in a way to skip it or leave it out all together. To answer your question about a plug-in, unfortunately you can't really do this so easily! I'll say it again, semantic markup, the cleaner the better.

good luck!

Comment: Hey thank you all for all the support. "Braille" was the first thing i heard about, so that's why i asked for more info about it. I got now a general idea about how it can be done but I have yet to look for easier solutions. If anyone has yet some better idea, I would appreciate. To reply to coments above, the accessibility support must be added for text of course, but can be also images.
I will let this question open for a few time yet. Hopefully there may be yet good ideas to come :))
Thanks guys

Comment: So to clarify, it seems as if you are asking for a prequalified template for Wordpress that addresses this for you as much as possible?